# Is Harry's Trunk Magical or (where is Harry's broom during the summer)?

Tags: harry-potter

Is Harry's trunk magically oversized (like Hermione's bag in book 7, or the Weasley car in book 2) to allow him to store his Firebolt in it? Is Harry able to hide, pack his broom so the Dursley's can't see it? the broom, almost more than anything, would repulse the Dursleys.

I don't recall there being a mention of his broom specifically being at the Dursely's or being transported to Platform 9 3/4, specifically in book 4 when the Weasley's come to collect Harry from the Dursleys. One of the twins climbs into the fireplace with Harry's trunk, but no mention of the Firebolt is made, yet, Harry has it at the Burrow after the World Cup.

Comment: Seems like a big trunk. *A large wooden trunk stood open at the
foot of his bed, revealing a cauldron, broomstick, black robes, and
assorted spellbooks.*

Comment: which book is that from?

Comment: Goblet of Fire, chapter 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Harry's trunk is magically enhanced to fit his broomstick

All Hogwarts school trunks come with extension charms

> **Hogwarts school trunks, like the majority of wizarding luggage, are issued with capacity enhancing or extension charms as standard.** These spells not only increase the interior dimensions of objects, while leaving the outer ones unchanged, they also render the contents lighter.
>
> <sub>[Pottermore - Extension Charms](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/extension-charms)</sub>

And we can see from the books that Harry keeps both his cauldron and broom inside his trunk at Privet Drive, something that would be hard to do without magic (unless he had a *really* big trunk.)

> Harry took his face out of his hands, opened his eyes, and stared around his bedroom as though expecting to see something unusual there. As it happened, there were an extraordinary number of unusual things in this room. **A large wooden trunk stood open at the foot of his bed, revealing a cauldron, broomstick, black robes, and assorted spellbooks.** Rolls of parchment littered that part of his desk that was not taken up by the large, empty cage in which his snowy owl, Hedwig, usually perched. On the floor beside his bed a book lay open; Harry had been reading it before he fell asleep last night. The pictures in this book were all moving. Men in bright orange robes were zooming in and out of sight on broomsticks, throwing a red ball to one another.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - Chapter 2</sub>

Comment: Given the extensibility of magical luggage, I have to ask why a trunk is needed at all, as opposed to something much smaller.  Why not just have a magical backpack, briefcase or purse?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Well, even with an extension charm, you'd still need a big enough opening to put the stuff into the container

Comment: @LegionMammal978 A broomstick doesn't require that large an opening.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - The trunk might need to be a believable size for a year away at boarding school, in case someone (taxi driver, security guard, etc) gets curious during the muggle-world part of the journey.